# Как реализовать проверку доступности функционала?

Tags: c#, архитектура, проектирование

У меня есть несколько сущностей:

```
public class Operation
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Act> Acts {get;set;}
}
public class Act
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int StateId {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<ActHistory> Histories {get;set;}
}
```

Мне необходимо проверять допустимость того или иного действия в соответствии с некоторой бизнес логикой, например:

Не допустить изменение экземпляра класса `Operation` при определенном состоянии акта(`Act`), или что редактировать операцию может только *владелец*.

для это я сделал метод

```
//Реализован в классе реализующем интерфейс `IOperationService`
public bool UserCanBeEditOperation(int userId, int operationId)
{
    //проверка соответствующих привилегий
}
```

работа с *сущностями* у меня разнесена по интерфейсам:

```
public interface IOperationService
{}
public interface IActService
{}
```

и все меня устраивало до тех пор пока мне не понадобилось ограничить метод создающий новый акт, данный функционал должен быть доступен только владельцу опеарции(`UserCanBeEditOperation`).

*Дублировать* метод `UserCanBeEditOperation` в класс реализующий `IActService` не хочу, передавать в качестве зависимости реализацию `IOperationService` из за одного метода, тоже считаю плохой идеей. На ум приходит только *вынесение* методов реализующих проверку в отдельный *интерфейс* который передавать в качестве зависимости в нужные классы.

Подскажите как поступить.

Comment: В случаях, когда я сомневаюсь в архитектуре классов, я обращаюсь к SOLID - если поглядеть на класс операции, то она по сути не должна знать контекста, она - просто операция, хранилище действий. Давая ей больше ответственностей вы двигаетесь в торону нарушения SRP. Так что я за новый класс, только не OperationService, а конкретно что он делает, типа OperationPermissionStrategy или типа того